# Most efficient way to transmit 32768 int16_t values over USB?

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, usb

I've got a project that produces 32768 int16_t values every 1.125 seconds. What's the most efficient way to "package" these for transmission over USB? Currently I'm pumping them out with commas between every value (and semicolons every 4096 values, with an "X" as the final character). It occurs to me that the host won't know that a given value is one or two bytes, so pre-allocating a buffer and waiting for it to fill won't work.

The USB device is programmed in C++ and the host is programmed in C#, if that helps. On the host end, I've got this function from a UWP sample:

```
private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

        uint ReadBufferLength = 98305;

        // Don't start any IO if we canceled the task
        lock (ReadCancelLock)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            // Cancellation Token will be used so we can stop the task operation explicitly
            // The completion function should still be called so that we can properly handle a canceled task
            DataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
            loadAsyncTask = DataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(cancellationToken);
        }

        UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            ReadBytesTextBlock.Text += DataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead);
            ReadBytesCounter += bytesRead;
            UpdateReadBytesCounterView();

        }
        rootPage.NotifyUser("Read completed - " + bytesRead.ToString() + " bytes were read", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
    }
```

Is there a method that allows me to read until a certain character is detected, like "X"? Ultimately these values need to be parsed into int16_t arrays so I can do some FFTs.

I admit that right now I'm really hacking this together and hoping it works, but I would love a reliable and robust way to do this properly.

Comment: How can a `int16_t` end up as single byte in your scenario?

Comment: @tkausl I'm either seeing that if the value is, for example, 3, then it's counted as one byte on the host end, or that it's counting each digit or character as a single byte. I really don't know.

Comment: Are you sending the values as text? Just send them as binary numbers, without any delimiter, and you'll end up with exactly 65536 bytes.

Comment: @tkausl /foreheadslap of course I was sending them as text instead of binary. Thanks for the wakeup call.

Comment: It's inappropriate to tag this with both c# and c++ - it isn't a question about both.   Please restrict the tags to things relevant to your actual specific question, not everything involved in the project at any point.

Comment: You also don't have to use `ReadString` there is also `ReadBytes(Byte[])` or `ReadInt16()` which would be more practical here(?)